# How to create diurnal average function for hourly data

Tags: r, function, average

I have hourly data for 3 months (June, July, August) and I'd like to show the average for each day hour for the three month period (e.g. average for all data from day hour 1, average for all data from day hour 2, etc.). I began writing a function but I'm still learning the best ways to write functions and loops to do what I need. My data does contain NA values but is a full data set for 24 hours/day for all 3 months. My current time vector is in Julian day/decimal day so hours for June 1 look like: 152.0000 152.0417 152.0833 152.1250 152.1667 152.2083 152.2500 152.2917 152.3333 152.3750 152.4167 152.4583 152.5000 152.5417 152.5833 152.6250152.6667 152.7083 152.7500 152.7917 152.8333 152.8750 152.9167 152.9583, where 152.0000 is June 1 (Julian day 152) at 12am and so on. Ideally I'd like the function to return 24 values that are the average for each hour. Eventually I'd also like to incorporate median, standard deviation, and standard error into this function. I did write some code so far but I really don't even know if what I wrote is even correct so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
# x is hourly data
# t is time vector, for my data I have Julian Decimal Day 
diurnal_avg <- function(x,t){ # input hourly and hourly time data
  dayhrvec <- rep(1:24,length.out=t)
  hr1points <- which(dayhrvec %in% 1)
}
```

Comment: Please edit data sample such as the output of `dput(head(mydata))` or proper table format. Also, include desired result with sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
hourly_data_frame %>%
  # Optional, for check: Convert day num to day of year
  mutate(day = floor(dates) + as.Date("2019-01-01") - 1) %>%
  # Convert decimal part of dates to hour of day
  mutate(hour = (dates %% 1) * 24) %>%
  # Summary time!
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarize(avg_value = mean(values),
            median    = median(values),
            std_dev   = sd(values))
## A tibble: 24 x 4
#    hour avg_value median std_dev
#   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 0          4.89   4.82   0.909
# 2 1.000      4.89   5.10   1.19 
# 3 2.         4.68   4.93   0.850
# 4 3          5.26   5.16   0.937
# 5 4.00       5.36   5.46   0.949
# 6 5.         5.05   5.10   0.883
# 7 6          5.13   5.09   0.851
# 8 7.00       5.14   5.21   0.887
# 9 8.         5.09   5.16   0.920
#10 9          5.04   4.84   1.11 
## ... with 14 more rows
```

Sample data

```
dates <- c(152 + 0:999/24)
hourly_data_frame <- data.frame(
  dates = dates,
  values = rnorm(1000, 5, 1)
)
```